# Authenticate in PHP with an OAuth 1.0a / x_auth server

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, xauth, oauth-1.0a

Need help authenticating w/ an OAuth 1.0a X_AUTH server in PHP. I've looked at several libs out there and cannot seem to figure to find one that will support an x_auth type setup.

Here is the POST that i'm attempting to create.

```
POST /oauth/access_token HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: 
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="a105eV7Wq6CyfnLfPHWIHlZfb96i4nLzvIBSUozn", 
oauth_nonce="kKhMKRxUpgfJ09iArtraNGc9huPdBkZI7GBkAd4exa0", 
oauth_signature="u2hPmgYlnZe7fLN3J0qPFQtl5tU%2FjLY%3D", 
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
oauth_timestamp="1390416425", 
oauth_version="1.0"

x_auth_username=api%2buser%40yourcompany.com&x_auth_mode=client_auth&x_auth_password=secretword1
```

And here are the libs i've look into so far and they dont have x_auth support.

- https://code.google.com/p/oauth-php
- http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/7700/post/1-Painless-OAuth-with-PHP.html#obtaining-the-access-token

Im looking for any assistance / guidance on how to authenticate w/ this type of oauth server or if you know of or can find any libraries that have x_auth support for oauth 1.0a.